# Problem with backup of list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2013, list, backup

I have got a list with many of records - More then 85 000 and I click Backup on SharePoint 2010. It backs up the list, but with less files then in another list. It shows me only 8 files, but when I backup any other list it show me 13 files. And Manifest file is so big.

[image]

Please tell me how to import this in destination location to SharePoint 2013? Is there special url definition which i can put, and import to destination location?

When I copy 5 another missing files it copy me this list, but to the site collection root site, not to the destination site told in: this command:

```
`Import-SPWeb -Identity **http://teamsite.vlad.local/aaa/aaa** -Path \\sp2010-itest\Exports\MyCusttomList.cmp -Verbose. At Bacuping list I get only this 8 files:`
```

Comment: How you trying to export the list? from Central admin> backup > export a site /list?

Comment: Yes, I do this solution. Choising a site, and choising a list. In all is going right but with my main list it genereiting this problem. When I tried to import this by comamnd it give me 2 list in one View.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are extracting the export file(.cmp) and you are seeing these files when you extracting it.

I would do the following to export and import.

- run the `Export-SPWeb http://site -Path "site export.cmp"`
- Move the .cmp file to destination.
- run this `Import-SPWeb http://site -Path export.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite`

You can also try to export via Central admin.

- [[Use Central Administration to export a site, list, or document library in SharePoint]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301(v=office.15).aspx#proc2)

Comment: But I must edit the list credentials because I moving this list from Sharepoint 2010 to 2013. So I mustchange version from 14 to 15.

Comment: When I start this command as You Have told me it move me list to the root Site Colection folder. Not to the Link wchich I choosen.

Comment: you are moving the list from sp2010 to sp2013?

Comment: Yes I'am It working on all list, but not with this, because it move me this list tothe root folder af Site Collection

Comment: if you are moving the a list(s) from sp2010 to sp2013 then their is no easy way....you have either go for Database migration or use 3rd party tool or their is another method which change the version...check more on this blog: http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: Yes I changing a Vesion from 14 to 15 thats why I extracing this list files. But after Extracing it haven't got a 5 files with main file SystemData.xml